# C# MVC5 Validate in Model with a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Within a Class I have a Static List of values which are allowed

```
private static List<string> allowedClassNames = new List<string> {"Real Estate", "Factored Debt"};
```

And I also have an attribute of that class, which I want to restrict to being values in that list.

```
        [Required]
        public string assetClassName { get; set; }
```

I want to do this at the model level, so it works in either a REST or view context.

How would I implement forcing the value in the submission to be limited to that list?

Thanks!

Here's Where I wound up - Not fully tested yet, but to give an idea to future posters.

```
    class MustContainAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public string Field { get; private set; }
    List<string> allowed;

    public MustContainAttribute(string validateField)
    {
        this.Field = validateField;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        switch (Field)
        {
            case "assetClassName":
                allowed = new List<string> { "Real Estate", "Factored Debt" }; 
                break;
            default:
                return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        if (!allowed.Contains(Field))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid Value");
        }else{
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to limit the values, or write your own validation attribute (say) `[MustContain("allowedClassNames")]` and in the  `IsValid()` method, compare the value with the values in the other property

Comment: An alternative would be to use an enum for the property. If a malicious user tried to submit anything other than one of the enum value, `ModelSate` will be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom validation attribute:

```
public class ClassNameRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {

        Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        MyAssetClass myAssetClass = (MyAssetClass)type.GetProperty("MyAssetClass").GetValue(instance, null);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myAssetClass.assetClassName))
        {
            if (myAssetClass.allowedClassNames.Contains(myAssetClass.assetClassName))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

And in your model:

```
    [ClassNameRequired(ErrorMessage="Your error message.")]
    public string assetClassName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not much point using a `ValidationAttribute` this way - is tied to a specific property in the model. You may as well do this with 2 lines of code in the controller method

Comment: I agree, but he/she asked how to do it at the model level. Regex is a good idea, but you know that saying...know they have two problems.

Comment: If you are going to do this, then the attribute needs to have a property for the other value (the `List`) so it flexible and can be reused

Comment: I used a modified version of this, to bring in the Field Name I'm trying to validate, then do a switch in the ValidationResult Method to load appropriate values based on the field name I'm validating. So it's reusable. Thanks both for your help!

Comment: @DiscontentDisciple no problem! Glad to hear you came up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can create your own ValidationAttribute.  This is useful if you have this validation on multiple models or if you want to implement client side validation as well (JavaScript)

However, A quick and easy way to do one off validations like this is the IValidatableObject.  You can use it as follows:

```
public class AssetModel:IValidatableObject
{
    private static List<string> allowedClassNames = new List<string> {"Real Estate", "Factored Debt"};

    [Required]
    public string assetClassName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!allowedClassNames.Contains(assetClassName)
        {
            yield new ValidationResult("Not an allowed value", new string[] { "assetClassName" } );
        }
    }
}
```